# width auto does not get centered

Tags: html, css, width, margins

Why does elements with auto width defined does not get centered when I try to assign the margin (left and right) auto for it?. Is there any trick other than the margins to center elements with auto width?

Here is the code:

```
<div style="width:auto; margin:0 auto 50px;">
 <a href="#">Dummy link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block` to, and remove `width:auto` from, your current `<div>`. Then, create an outer `<div>`, if you don't have one already, and add `text-align: center` to it.

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
  <div style="display:inline-block; margin:0 auto 50px;">
    <a href="#">Dummy link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/uLp7qj3e/

Comment: Works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You may give `text-align:center` to parent div if any.

To use `margin-auto` we need to specify width of the div. `auto` will take 100% width for div and p tags.

If you can find out and give specific width for div so that, else based on your browser suppport you use property `width:max-content;` , read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width#max-content)

You may use browser hack for this as:

```
width: intrinsic;           /* Safari/WebKit uses a non-standard name */
width: -moz-max-content;    /* Firefox/Gecko */
width: -webkit-max-content; /* Chrome */
```

Example snippet:

```html
<div style="background:red;margin:auto;width:intrinsic;width:-moz-max-content;width:-webkit-max-content;">
  <a href="#">Dummy link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This works, but what I was really trying to accomplish is to create a box that contains "Dummy link" word  and this box should be the exact width of the word. When I give it a width auto and a background color it stretches all the way horizontally.

Comment: @AndrewMk : Give the property `display:inline-block`, to your div and then it will width not more than that of its content. Is that what you want?

Comment: Did that now the div that contains the anchor is not centered, although I have margin:0 auto 50px;